# i can't run modules in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
Module Transpose (transpose) where
import Data.List 
transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
map sum $ transpose [[0,3,5,9],[10,0,0,9],[8,5,1,1]]
```

Prelude> :reload

dosya.hs:32:30: error: parse error on input ‘where’
|
32 | Module Transpose (transpose) where    |                              ^^^^^
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( dosya.hs, interpreted )
Failed, no modules loaded.

Comment: `module` is with a lowrcase.

Comment: But the `transpose` signature does not make much sense, since that is imported through `Data.List`, and here it looks as if you want to define it yourself.

Comment: The last line is also wrong: you can't simply write an expression like that in a .hs file, you need to write a definition like `result = map sum $ ....` and then ask GHCi to evaluate `result`.

Comment: I  tried with a lowercase letter. how should I define transpose or result myself

Answer (score 1):

There is already a `transpose` function in `Data.List`, but it looks like you don't want to use it.  Instead, you are trying to define a `Transpose` module that exports your own `transpose` function, which you can import into other modules, right?

If so, there are several problems with your attempt:

```
-- "module" must be lowercase
Module Transpose (transpose) where

-- this import may interfere with your own definition of `transpose`
import Data.List 

-- this type signature has no associated definition
transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]

-- you can't include this code in the middle of the module;
-- it needs to be part of a function definition
map sum $ transpose [[0,3,5,9],[10,0,0,9],[8,5,1,1]]
```

What you probably want is a `Transpose.hs` file that contains:

```
-- contents of Transpose.hs
module Transpose (transpose) where

import Data.List hiding (transpose) -- don't use Data.List definition

transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose = error "to be implemented"
```

and then another file `Test.hs` that imports and tests it within the `main` function:

```
-- contents of Test.hs
import Transpose

main = do
    print $ map sum $ transpose [[0,3,5,9],[10,0,0,0],[8,5,1,1]]
```

With those two files in place, you should be able to load `Test` and run `main` from GHCi:

```
λ> :l Test
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, interpreted ) [flags changed]
Ok, modules loaded: Main, Transpose (/scratch/buhr/stack/global-project/.stack-work/odir/Transpose.o).
Collecting type info for 1 module(s) ... 
λ> main
*** Exception: to be implemented
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ./Transpose.hs:7:13 in main:Transpose
```

or compile and run it:

```
$ ghc Test.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling Transpose        ( Transpose.hs, Transpose.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking Test ...
$ ./Test
Test: to be implemented
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ./Transpose.hs:7:13 in main:Transpose
```

Comment: I’m not certain what the original intent was, but I suspect the signature may have been part of the attempt to import or re-export the function, like declarations in some other languages. In that case, to simply *use* the standard `transpose`, the signature `transpose :: …` can be omitted, and `transpose` can be imported with `import Data.List (transpose)`, or the original `import Data.List`.